# RecyclerView Items are not showing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

FolderListAdapter Code

```
public class FolderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FolderListAdapter.myViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Folder> folderList;

    public FolderListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Folder> folderList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.folderList = folderList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.folder_view, parent, false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Folder folder = folderList.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(folder.getFolder()).into(holder.imageView);
        holder.folder_name.setText(folder.getFolder().getName());
        holder.folder_item_count.setText(folder.getFilesList().size() + " Items");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return folderList.size();
    }

    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final ShapeableImageView imageView;
        private final TextView folder_name;
        private final TextView folder_item_count;
        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.folder_image_view);
            folder_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.folder_name_text_view);
            folder_item_count = itemView.findViewById(R.id.folder_items_count_text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity Code for RecyclerView

```
FolderListAdapter adapter = new FolderListAdapter(this, folderList);

RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.folderRecyclerView;
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
```

XML CODE OF recycler view

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/folder_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/folder_view" />
```

folder_view.xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:id="@+id/folder_image_view"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folder_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Camera"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/folder_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/folder_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folder_image_view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/folder_items_count_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="600 Items"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/folder_name_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/folder_name_text_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_folder.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.addFiles.FoldersActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/folder_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**
[image: Output Screenshot]

- The size of folderList is 2
- I also check the size of adapter. It is also 2
- I also tried by making a new Adapter but it also does not work.
  I don't know where I am making mistake and why it is now showing nothing in activity.

Comment: Hi there, can you change `android:layout_width="0dp"`  `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `match_parent` ?

Comment: Post your item layout "folder_view, parent". Also the layout that holds your _RecyclerVIew_.

Comment: What is the height and width of the _ConstraintLayout_ that contains the _RecyclerView_? Can you post that XML?

Comment: Height and width of constraint layout is "match_parent"

Comment: Everything looks OK. Run the app and look in the Layout Inspector of Android Studio to see if the layout is actually displayed or not. You can get the size of the various views from the Layout Inspector if they are on the screen at all. Depending on what you discover, it should send you down a path to figuring out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

##### Change 1 :

In the `xml` set attribute `android:layout_width="0dp"` to `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

##### Change 2 :

In your `MainActivity` code set `LayoutManager` to the `RecyclerView` before setting up adapter. so the code goes this way :

```
//Defining RecyclerView and setting LayoutManager
RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.folderRecyclerView;
FolderListAdapter adapter = new FolderListAdapter(this, folderList);

//Setting up Adapter
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```